# ssh key github added still asking user/pw

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I have first generate a key for my github. Then add it to and ID . Copy past the content of id_rsa.pub into my github account and test the connection with this command :

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

followed by this :

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (***.**.***.*)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA****:************************************.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,***.**.***.' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Hi ****! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

After this trying to push something, it still asking me my username and password I don't know why.

Comment: Have you switched the remote from HTTPS to SSH?

Comment: Is the `ssh-agent` still running and have you `ssh-add`ed the private key to it?

Comment: I have generated my ssh with : 
```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "emailadress"
```
Then 
```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```
and add the key to it 
```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current remote will be using https protocol. That is why it is still asking for password.

use `git remote show origin | grep URL` to see  the current remote URL for origin

if it starts with `https://` it will ask for username and password.

Then remove it by `git remote rm origin`

Then add ssh url by `git remote add origin <url>`
Make sure that you provide ssh url here,  it should be something like `git@github.com..`

Go to your github repo and click on green clone button and if it is in https format change it to ssh 
[image]

Use the `Use SSH` link to change it to SSH

Then you should see the ssh url

[image]

Comment: It was indeed as https. I get the result I wanted with your answer thank you ! There is something I can do to give feedback such as +1 or rep comment ? Im new ^^

Comment: Glad it worked. Just marking it as accepted answer would be enough, and I see that you've already done that :)

Answer (score 0):

Github does not provide SSH access. Your command is trying to connecto to github by ssh as connection to a remote computer. This is not what you are allowed to do.

What you can do with the SSH keys in github now, is clone repositories, commit, etc.

```
git clone git@github.com:<project>
```

And with SSH you are allowed to do actions on a project with the registered user. Now you can commit, perform pull requests, ...

Answer (score 0):

All I want at this point is to no enter my username and password whenever I want to push my stuff on github. I made it work. But a day I had to create an other ssh key and id for my VPS but I overwrited it, I didn't know that I have to create one id/key per file.

So I delete known_host and erase the content of rsa.pub and rsa, and create a brand new one but it don't work..